# how to upload image using nusoap

Tags: php, nusoap

hi  to all i am using Nusoap class for making the webservice.
i am newer to webservice . can u help me how to upload image using Nusoap.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have read your question twice and still don't understand it.

Comment: i need the code to upload image in webservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello no need do any coding 
just go through this example.you will get your answer 
http://www.my-php-scripts.net/index.php/php-upload-image-using-web-service-soap-advanced-php.html